# bootstrap container max-width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to set the `max-width` of a bootstrap container using the default settings? (without modifying the code)

I am trying to set the max-width of the container to 540px, but the css rule gets overwritten to 1140px;

**Code:**

```
<div class="container-sm">
  <div class="border border-primary">
    <p>This content should have max-width of 540px</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

https://codepen.io/catalingavan/pen/NWGapKa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap containers (container-sm, container-md, container-lg, container-xs) change their width based on the type of device and class used.

so in your case - since you're using container-sm, I simply created an override

```
.container-sm {
    max-width: 540px;
}
```

Modified your codepen - https://codepen.io/AbhijatSaxena/pen/GRpMWZr

(I would also recommend setting the max-width for other types of containers as well for consistency)

Reference from bootstrap site 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, I want to know if it is possible to achieve this without modifying the css.

Comment: As I mentioned above - the widths are re-calculated each time whenever you resize your browser - so I doubt that there's any other way to get around this.